# Visual Composer > Dependency not working

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a plugin and trying to implement Visual Composer in my plugin codes.
I am using the following codes for implementing dependency.

```
$params = array(
array(
    "type" => "checkbox",
    "heading" => "Checkbox 1",
    "param_name" => "check1",
),
array(
    "type" => "textfield",
    "heading" => "My textbox",
    "param_name" => "text1",
    "group" => "Group 1",
    "dependency" => array(
        "element" => "check1",
        "value" => "true"
    )
),
);

vc_map( array(
    "name" => "My Shortcode",
    "base" => "my_shortcode",
    "class" => "",
    "category" => "ABC",
    "params" => $params
));
```

But these codes are not working.

Answer (score 3):

```
$params = array(
array(
    "type" => "checkbox",
    "heading" => "Checkbox 1",
    "param_name" => "check1",
     "value" => array(
            "" => "true"
    ),
),
array(
    "type" => "textfield",
    "heading" => "My textbox",
    "param_name" => "text1",
    "group" => "Group 1",
    "dependency" => array(
        "element" => "check1",
        "value" => "true"
    )
),
);

vc_map( array(
    "name" => "My Shortcode",
    "base" => "my_shortcode",
    "class" => "",
    "category" => "ABC",
    "params" => $params
));
```

Just set the value `"value" => array("" => "true"),` in parent array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$params = array(
array(
    "type" => "checkbox",
    "heading" => "Checkbox 1",
    "param_name" => "check1",
),
array(
    "type" => "textfield",
    "heading" => "My textbox",
    "param_name" => "text1",
    "group" => "Group 1",
    "dependency" => array(
        "element" => "check1",
        "value" => "1"
    )
),
);

vc_map( array(
    "name" => "My Shortcode",
    "base" => "my_shortcode",
    "class" => "",
    "category" => "ABC",
    "params" => $params
));
```

You can use like this.

Comment: You mean only difference is "value" => "true" into "value" => "1"